# Can I install Visual Studio 2010 Professional (x86) on an x64 machine?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, x86-64

I have an msdn subscription, but (for the life of me) I cannot find the download for Visual Studio 2010 Professional x64.

Is the x64 version included in the X86 DVD?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Visual Studio 2010 does not have a 64-bit version, only 32-bit. The 32-bit version will work fine on 64-bit Windows.

Comment: X64 Windows can always run 32 apps. The reason is this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WoW64. In task manager when you see proc.exe*32 the "*32" means it's being run under WOW64. Neat right?